# signaling an error in FreeMarker

Tags: java, templates, error-handling, freemarker

Scenario:

- I have a Java program that is fixed, that uses FreeMarker templates
- I am the one writing the FreeMarker templates.
- In one of my templates, I want to check a value, and if it is out of bounds, signal an error back up to the application.

How can I do this? There is the [`attempt/recover`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_attempt.html) mechanism analogous to `try/catch`, but there's no equivalent to `throw`. (other than the `stop` directive)

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass `RuntimeException` or `TemplateException`, then throw that exception inside the template and catch it outside `Template.process`. To throw the exception, you could create a custom directive like:

```
public class ThrowMyExceptionDirective implements TemplateDirectiveModel {

    @Override
    public void execute(Environment env, Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars, TemplateDirectiveBody body)
            throws TemplateException, IOException {
        throw new MyTemplateException();
    }

}
```

add it to the data-model (or to an `#import` or to the `Configuration` as shared variable) with name `"throwMyException"`, and then in the template you can do:

```
<@throwMyException />
```

Comment: that's it? Huh, I saw the bit about custom directives, it looked a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass objects into the freemarker template.  Create a Signal object that holds an error value.  Then in the template, when you want to return an error, call the set() method on the Signal object with the error.

Then when freemarker returns from the processing the template, your code can check the Signal object for a returned error.  It can throw an Exception at that point if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they added this by now: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_stop.html

```
<#stop>
<#stop reason>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FreeMarker like:

```
Template tpl = configuration.getTemplate(tplName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Environment env = tpl.createProcessingEnvironment(myContextObject, out);
env.setOutputEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
env.process();
```

I want to stop / die from within an expression. So I simply added a method to `myContextObject`:

```
public void die(final String reason) {
  throw new IllegalStateException(reason);
}
```

Which allows you to do something like this in your template:

```
${die("Reason")}
```